# CkEditor 4.17.1 changes impossible

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

I use ck editor 4.17.1 with angular and I integrate the emoji and when I modify the json no modifications even if I delete the file.

I've emptied the browser cache, the server cache and set timestamps, but nothing works.

Do you have any solutions?